# TableViewの中にViewを配置し、スクロールするとViewも追従して表示しつづけたい

Tags: xcode, swift3, uitableview, uiscrollview

[image: main.storyboard]

現在、Point View というゲーム点数を表示するだけのViewを配置しています。
この点数はTableView下にスクロールをしても常に表示したいと考えています。
(上から下にスクロールしたときも定位置で表示したい)

しかし下記のようにしてもうまく動作できておりません。

```
    import UIKit

class TopTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, Calk {

    @IBOutlet var tableview: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var pointView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var dispPoint: UILabel!


/* 中略 */

/* スクロール時 */

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        pointView.frame = CGRect(x:0+scrollView.contentOffset.x, y:0, width:0, height:0)


    }
```

[image: 追従失敗]

上記画像のように、Viewが追従表示されないだけではなく
Viewのカラーがなくなり、上にずれてしまいます。
一体どのように改善すればよいのか、お手数ですがどなたかご回答をよろしくお願いします。

Comment: `UITableView`のスクロールとは独立して固定的な位置にViewを表示したい場合、・`UITableView`の外側に独立したViewを配置する、・`UITableView`のsection headerとする、などの方法も考えられるかと思いますが、ご検討されましたでしょうか。`UITableView`は確かに`UIScrollView`のサブクラスとして実装されていますが、それ以上の情報は公開されていない(今後公開される可能性も極めて低い)ため、`UIScrollView`では通用する手法を`UITableView`に適用しても、その結果は「未定義」と言うことになります。現行iOSで、その詳細な動作を研究して何とか動くようにしたとしても、iOSのバージョンが0.0.1上がるだけで動かなくなる可能性もあります。(Appleは「未定義」動作に変化があっても何の告知もしてくれません。)ご質問文の内容だけでは、どのような要件があるのかわかりませんが、「`UITableView`に直接サブビューを配置する」と言う現在の手法については(もし何らかの方法で動くようにできたとしても)避けた方が良いように思われます。

Comment: なるほど、継承していても同じようにメソッドが動くわけではないのですね。TableViewControllerで実装するのをやめ、ViewControllerにTableViewの部品を置く方法に変更しました。前者の方法だとMain.storyboardに独立したViewを置けなかったためです。後者の方法でViewを配置するとそのまま定位置で表示されました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: ご所望の動作をするためのお手伝いができたのであれば何よりです。できれば、最終的にどのようなstoryboard設定・コードになったのか、「回答」として投稿してくださるようお願いします。表題のような動作を実現したいと思われる方々は他にもたくさんおられるでしょうから、回答の形で投稿していただくことで、このスレッドをそれらの方々にとっても有用なものとすることができます。